# Set product language when post new product

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Woocommerce and WPML translation plugin. I'm using 4 languages. The default language is English. I use a form to post new products on frontend. For instance when I post a new product under Italian language, the language code for this product is Italian. However, I try to achieve, that all posted products have English as default language. So I try to use my hook where I set also the quantity for each posted product to 1. Unfortunately I cannot update the language code with the hook. What I'm doing wrong?

```
add_action('save_post', 'myWoo_savePost', 10, 2);

function myWoo_savePost($postID, $post) {
    if (isset($post->post_type) && $post->post_type == 'product') {

    update_post_meta($post->ID, '_manage_stock', 'yes');
        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_stock', '1');

        //set language code to en
        $set_language_args = array(
        'language_code' => 'en',
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use the post meta for a product, in that you can store  your default language. for, eg. update_post_meta($prdocut_post_id, 'language_code', 'en'); .

Comment: Hi Sunil, unfortunately it does not work too (you had a typo in $product...)

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this bug here is my code

add_action('save_post', 'myWoo_savePost', 10, 2);

```
function myWoo_savePost($postID, $post) {
    if (isset($post->post_type) && $post->post_type == 'product') {

    update_post_meta($post->ID, '_manage_stock', 'yes');
    update_post_meta($post->ID, '_stock', '1');

    }

    //start translation
        $inserted_post_ids = $post->ID;

    if ( $inserted_post_ids) {
        // https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_element_type/
        $wpml_element_type = apply_filters( 'wpml_element_type', 'post_product' );

        // get the language info of the original post
        // https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_element_language_details/
        $get_language_args = array('element_id' => $inserted_post_ids, 'element_type' => 'post_product' );
        $original_post_language_info = apply_filters( 'wpml_element_language_details', null, $get_language_args );

        $set_language_args = array(
            'element_id'    => $inserted_post_ids,
            'element_type'  => $wpml_element_type,
            'trid'   => $original_post_language_info->trid,
            'language_code'   => 'en',
            'source_language_code' => $original_post_language_info->language_code
        );

        do_action( 'wpml_set_element_language_details', $set_language_args );
    }
    //end translation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For poly-lang i added below code.

```
global $polylang;
         
   $language_code='de';
     
   if (function_exists('pll_set_post_language')) {                
      pll_set_post_language($post_id, $language_code);
   } else {
      error_log(print_r($post_id . ' poly-lang not found!'));
   }
```